# Find the date that is closest to the desired date without going past and matching serial number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "column I" with data in it for rework date and "column G" for assembly date.
In "column J" I want the result of using "Rework Date" to find a date that is closest to "Date of Assembly" column without going over.  It can be the same date as the assembly or before just not over.  To tie it together, the "Rework Serial" must be the exact same as the "Serial" in "column E".
Note: I need the time in there as well as some instances that happen on the same day will have different times.

I was trying to use the "Rework Date" to look through the entire "Date of Assembly" column and after it compared each one it returned the maximum as long as it did not exceed and the serials were the same.  I did not know how to use the one rework to look through the other column with those details and move onto the next rework date and do the same.

I did create somewhat of a column that looked through the data then did a vlookup on the max, but that would cause a column to be created for each rework in the column and that would be too much.  I might be overthinking this, but some input would be much appreciated.

[image]

The image shows a snippet of code I tried along with the excel as a whole I am working with.  It shows the method of creating columns per "Rework Date" instance.

Trying to use VBA to go through the entire column of Serial and see if it is equal to Rework Serial then concatenate that value in column "L".
From here I was hoping to compare the date also and return the value of the date that it the max without going over.  This code works for returning to one cell, how would it be done for each cell for each rework?

I got further, but for some reason on every third time through the loop, it bugs out at

```
AssemD = DateValue(Cells(x,7))
```

with a type mismatch.  I do not understand this as it ran without the For Each j loop, but I am trying to nest it so that after it does all its compares and finds the max, it then writes that max to Cells(y,12) that is the y counter that keeps up with the j.

```
Sub RecentDate()
    Dim i As Range, j As Range, x As Integer, y As Integer, AssemD As Date, ReworkD As Double, AssemTi As Double, ReworkTi As Double, AssemTot As Double, ReworkTot As Double, MaxDate As Date
    x = 1
    y = 1
    'Set i = Range("E1:E12")
    For Each j In Range("I1:I12")
        For Each i In Range("G1:G12")
            AssemD = DateValue(Cells(x, 7))
            ReworkD = DateValue(Cells(1, 9))
            AssemTi = TimeValue(Cells(x, 7))
            ReworkTi = TimeValue(Cells(1, 9))
            AssemTot = CDbl(AssemD) + CDbl(AssemTi)
            ReworkTot = CDbl(ReworkD) + CDbl(ReworkTi)

            If ReworkTot >= AssemTot And Cells(1, 8) = Cells(x, 5) Then
                MaxDate = Cells(x, 7)
            End If
            Cells(x, 13) = MaxDate
            x = x + 1
        Next i
        Cells(y, 12) = MaxDate
        y = y + 1
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: You should look into using `index(match())`, using a reverse order (so searching from bottom to top).

Comment: @Luuklag  Will it need to be sorted or can this work with both columns being out of order?

Comment: That would require for them to be in order, otherwise you would need a more elaborate approach. Using VBA for example you could read everything in an array per Serial number, sort it, and find matches.

Comment: I have moved to trying VBA.                                                            
 Sub RecentDate()
    Dim i As Range, j As Range
    For Each i In Range("H2:H13")
        For Each j In Range("E2:E13")
            If Cells(i, 8) = Cells(j, 5) Then
                Cells(2, 12) = Cells(2, 12) & ", " & Cells(i, 8)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub                                                                                          Here I wanted to check the serial in rework with each in assem and if the same concat each one, but they are left blank

Comment: please post code in your question, using the edit button on the bottom left. Format it as code, by selecting it and pressing ctrl+k.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use VBA, but got it with the following code.

```
Sub RecentDate()
    Dim i As Range, j As Range, x As Integer, y As Integer, AssemD As Date, ReworkD As Double
    Dim AssemTi As Double, ReworkTi As Double, AssemTot As Double, ReworkTot As Double, MaxDate As Date, LineFault As String
    x = 1
    y = 1
    'Set i = Range("E1:E12")
    For Each j In Range("I1:I12")
        For Each i In Range("G1:G12")
            AssemD = DateValue(Cells(x, 7))
            ReworkD = DateValue(Cells(y, 9))
            AssemTi = TimeValue(Cells(x, 7))
            ReworkTi = TimeValue(Cells(y, 9))
            AssemTot = CDbl(AssemD) + CDbl(AssemTi)
            ReworkTot = CDbl(ReworkD) + CDbl(ReworkTi)

            If ReworkTot >= AssemTot And Cells(y, 8) = Cells(x, 5) Then
                MaxDate = Cells(x, 7)
                LineFault = Cells(x, 6)
            End If
            Cells(x, 13) = MaxDate
            x = x + 1
        Next i
        x = 1
        Cells(y, 12) = MaxDate
        Cells(y, 14) = LineFault
        y = y + 1
        MaxDate = "1/1/1900 12:00"
        LineFault = ""
    Next j
End Sub
```

Was definitely overthinking this one.